# Assigning an number to beside a data validation source

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

The image linked below probably explains best. In short, I want to assign an item from column 1 (which is a data validation list sourced from column 1, in column 4) to a purchase price that I enter. That’s already good.

What I’m looking for is for that purchase price to appear in column 3 beside the correct item chosen from the data validation list. Then I can compare the difference between the budget and actual purchase amount.

Much appreciated, thank you!

https://ibb.co/xSsSQ6X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete everything in ranhe C4:C and use this in C4:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A4:A; D:E; 2; 0)))
```

Comment: Thank you - but isn't that the cell where I have my data validation list?

I made a more precise screenshot with labels. https://ibb.co/MfWB4N7

Comment: @Emil answer updated

Comment: Thank you so much. In my actual, D and E are not beside each other. How can I make it two targeted columns instead of an inclusive range? For example, D is the dropdown, and F is the accounted price.

Comment: @Emil instead of `D:E` use `{D:D, F:F}` or `{D:D\ F:F}` based on your localization

Comment: Thank you very much. My final question is this: If I account two or more items for the same item, can they add? I appreciate all your help. By the way, this is my actual: =INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(AV14:AV, {BH:BH, BC:BC}, 2, 0)))

Comment: @Emil add where? in accounting or bugeting? can you show some example?

Comment: Going back to my original example, if I were to account $12 and assign it to "dog", but then the next day make another purchase for $6 contributing to "dog", can that add up to $18 in that spot beside the reference list? (Will certainly get you a coffee for this, thank you)

Comment: Thank you: I'm getting this error: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: ADD_COL_TO_GROUP_BY_OR_AGG: Col1.

Comment: @Emil try:  `=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(AV14:AV, QUERY({BH:BH, BC:BC}, "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"), 2, 0)))`